# How would you automatically add '/' to a date in mmyyyy format with javascript?

Tags: javascript

`enter code here`All the code I have is for the HTML page which makes a text area to type in the expiration date for a credit card. I'm having trouble getting the cool feature to automatically insert a slash '/' between the month "mm" and year "yyyy".

```
//in HTML
Card Expiration: <input type="month" id="exp" name="expiredt" placeholder="XX/XXXX" maxlength="7">
                 <script src="addSlash.js"></script>
```

I don't have any JS for this because nothing I had worked.

Comment: Please share in which formate you are getting data?

Comment: It would be great if you could show what attempts you've made to solve this issue yourself. There are a number of questions on Stack Overflow about this type of problem already, have you read any of those?

Comment: @SachinShah the title is "How would you automatically add '/' to a date in **mmyyyy format** with javascript?" (emphasis mine), so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should update it in real time. Remember to validate the input properly.

```js
function addSlashes (element) {
 
    let ele = document.getElementById(element.id);
    ele = ele.value.split('/').join('');    // Remove slash (/) if mistakenly entered.
    if(ele.length < 4 && ele.length > 0){
        let finalVal = ele.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('/');

        document.getElementById(element.id).value = finalVal;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="dateInput" onkeyup="addSlashes(this)" maxlength=7>
```

Comment: This currently throws an error if backspaced out completely, because it tries to join a null value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of input mask libraries out there that do this sort of thing better. If I were going to roll it from scratch, I might do something like this. It's kind of overkill for your question, while still not being all that robust an approach. But if you're looking for a quick and dirty solution, this might be good enough.

```js
function handleExpInput(event) {
  var charCode = event.key.charCodeAt(0);
  // Filtered to numeric keys (not part of the ask)
  if(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
     // Extra handing around the case where the / is at the front of a highlighted block (again not part of the ask)
     if(event.target.selectionStart === 2) {
       if(event.target.selectionEnd !== 2) {
         // Bumps the highlighted section off of the / if so.
         event.target.selectionStart += 1
       } else {
         // Adds the slash before handling the third character.
         event.target.value += '/'
       }
     }
  } else {
    // Whitelisting for control keys
    switch(charCode) {
      case 8:
      case 9:
        break;
      default:
        event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('exp').onkeypress = handleExpInput;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exp" name="expiration" value="" placeholder="mm/yyyy" maxlength="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var expire_date = document.getElementById('exp').value;
 if(expire_date.length == 2){
   document.getElementById('exp').value = expire_date +'/';
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exp" onkeypress="myFunction()" placeholder="mm/yyyy" maxlength="7">
```